# Methods and properties

Tags: php, database, oop, object, config

I'm fuzzy on the terminology, and I've tried searching - but have so far not gotten any wiser.
I'm trying to learn OOP in PHP, and I'm trying to write a configuration class that stores value/key pairs in a DB. It's working perfectly well, but not quite the way I want it to work.

Anyway, here's what I do:

```
$config=new Config();
$keyValue=$config->keyName;                      // Get key value
$config->keyName=$newKeyvalue;                   // Set key value
$description=$config->getDescription($keyName);  // get description
$config->setDescription($keyName, $description); // set description
```

Here's what I want to do (only the two last lines, since those are the relevant ones):

```
$description=$config->keyName->description;     // get description
$config->keyName->description=$newDescription;  // set description
```

Setting/getting key values is done with _*get()/*_set(), but how do I set "subproperties" of a key the same way?

Edit:
Solved it. Working class with _*get/*_set/_*isset/*_unset working properly is here: http://pastebin.com/TFAA8Dcq

(Note: Little error checking is done, and this class allows for setting dynamic object names, which is probably not the safest thing in the world)

Comment: If i'm not mistaken you want your variables to have a description right? You should use an array then `keyName` should be an array with `keyValue` and `keyDescription`. There is not a way for 'subproperties'.

Comment: There is a way - and I found it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make the "keyName" property a class as well. For example, `$config->keyName = new stdClass;` would allow you to then set `$config->keyName->property = "something else";`

Obviously you could no longer set the keyName property directly to a string anymore in that case, though. You can, however, implement the __toString magic method in PHP classes to automatically return a string variable when a Class is treated implicitly as a string.

Comment: Ok, so... if I use __get and __set to create a "keyName" object, that has a "value" and "description" method... 
Calling `$config->keyName->value($newValue)` should set the value, calling `$config->keyName` gets the current value via `__tostring()`.

Or maybe I could just make the child object dynamic the same way the parent object is, and use `$value=$config->keyName->value` instead of `$value=$config->keyname`. That'll break a lot of existing code though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I made it work by making __get/__set spawn another object and using __tostring.

Complete code is far too long to paste here, but I pasted it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/e1DzhZE4) if anyone else is interested.